# Store homemade kefir with paper towel on top or close the lid normally?

Tags: kefir

I made my first batch of kefir with a paper "breathable" towel over the top of a glass container. If I want to store the output in refrigerator, do I have to make it "breathable", or normally close it with solid lid?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you'll drink it quickly, you can store it with an airtight lid, but this will make it "fizzy". Personally, I'd store it with a breathable lid to avoid carbonating it, and possibly causing it to explode. There's still live/active cultures, even when you remove the kefir grains.

Edit: quickly, as in a day or so